# WebAPI not finding my controller in App_Data folder

Tags: asp.net-web-api

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

in global.asax.cs i do:
WebApiConfig.Register(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
Break point confirms that the route is being registered.

In the App_Data folder i place a folder WebApi and put in a BlogPosts.cs with the following content:

```
public class BlogPosts : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

What more do I have to do to get the website to use the WebAPI ?
`http://localhost:49396/api/BlogPosts` gives me:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:49396/api/BlogPosts'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'BlogPosts'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Therefore the WebAPI have been registed correct but it just dont find the ApiController in App_Data folder. I properly am missing something. (Its not a MVC4 project, but a website that i try to add a api to).

Comment: App_Data folder is why you have to use?

Comment: Get under a `Class Library`, it makes sense to.

Comment: Its under App_Data to hide it such clients cant download the file? Its a website structure. not a WebApp solution in visual studio like mvc4

Comment: Properly i want it in the App_code instead of app_data, going over http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx now

Comment: In this instance, configure the server side can be true. But the truth, should be built!

Answer (score 2):

`App_Data` is not normally used for this type of scenario. It could very well be that you *BlogPosts.cs* file is not set to **Compile** but something like **Content**. So, in solution explorer click on *BlogPosts.cs*, go to properties and change `Build Action` settings to **Compile**.

Another problem is that your `BlogPosts` is missing **Controller** suffix. Rename your class to `BlogPostsController`.

It would probably be better if you create a special folder where you would keep your Web API controllers, like **ApiControllers**.

Comment: I do not have the Build Action porperti. Its a website opened with Webmatrix and clicking open in visual studio.